# Chinese Flag is not changing in the language switcher

Tags: magento-1.9, language, switcher

On [my website](http://www.meesfrenkelfrank.com/magento): if i switch to *Chinese language* the **flag** is not changing in the language switcher? The other languages are working fine. E.g. if you switch to *French*, its showing the French flag...

This is the **language.phtml** i am using:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="polyglot-language-switcher" data-grid-columns="1" data-anim-effect="fade" data-open-mode="click" data-anim-speed="0.1" >
    <ul style="display: none">
        <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang):?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" data-lang-id="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt=""> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It's probably some settings. Does it have a proper homepage etc?

Comment: Ahh wait, I misunderstood. Please post the phtml file with the language switcher. It's probably missing some if else statement

Comment: @Sander Mangel Yes it has a general homepage for all store views. Test the other languages, they are working fine...!

Comment: please post the phtml of the language switcher. We'll need som actual code to debug your problem

Comment: Found it! tl;dr: change storecode to ZH for China. For full explanation see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through your javascript files I found this piece

```
    $j('.polyglot-language-switcher').polyglotLanguageSwitcher({
        selectedLang: function () {
            return $j('html').attr('lang');
        }
    });
```

Which basically uses the `lang` attribute of the HTML tag to set the current language. Testing this on several stores the language is always set correctly.

`<html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js">` for English, 
`<html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js">` for French... But for Chinese `<html lang="zh" id="top" class="no-js">`

And since you're using the code `CN` but the language is `ZH it doesn't match.`

`ZH` is the ISO2 language code that Magento uses while the language switcher uses the store codes you've provided. The quickest and cleanest solution is to simply change the storecode to `ZH`. Any other solution would require a hard coded rewrite of the code

Comment: Ok thanks. I will approve your answer. Additional you have to change the flag-name to `zh.png` (originally it was `cn.png`).

Comment: Ah you're right. Glad it's solved